# What to do when the Gram matrix of an underdetermined system is singular?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, numerical-linear-algebra, svd

I am currently trying to speedrun my linear analysis course, I have been doing pretty well so far, but hit a wall when the lectures started hitting on SVD and under/overdetermined systems of equations. The set-up is as follows:

Suppose you have an equation of type:
$ A\vec{x} = \vec{b} $, where A $ \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n} $, generally a non-square matrix. For the case that this system is underdetermined, we are trying to find a solution $\vec{x} = \vec{x}_p + Ker(A) $, where $\vec{x}_p$ would generaly be any particular solution, whose "tip" sits at the null space of the matrix, shifted from the origin. In our case, we are trying to at least find the solution with the smallest possible norm, which would be the one perpendicular to the null space, i.e., lying in the row space, or in other words $ \vec{x} = A^T\vec{z} $ for some $\vec{z}$.

Now if we expand our original equation, multiplying it from the left by $A^T$, we get:

$
 A^TA\vec{x} = A^T\vec{b}
$, where we would usually label $G :=A^TA$ as the Gram matrix (if the inner product of that space is indentical to the dot product, otherwise we would add the matrix representation of the inner product between $A^T$ and $A$).

This is where my problem starts. The set-up further says that if the columns of the Gram matrix are linearly independent, then there exists a matrix $G^{-1}$, giving us (multiplying by the inverse from the left):

$ \vec{x} = G^{-1}A^T\vec{b} $

Using the fact, that $\vec{x} = A^T\vec{z}$, our particular solution looks like:

$\vec{x_0} = A^TG^{-1}A^T\vec{b}$

The problem is, what if the Gram matrix itself ISN'T linearly independent? What is the visual representation of that? And how do we find the "smallest" solution in that case?

Comment: If you have the SVD of $A$, then the solution is given by multiplication with the Moore-Penrose inverse of $A$, which yields the minimal-norm solution.

Comment: I still haven't got the SVD yet, it is part of the chapter, though. Which should be in the next lecture. I am trying to "speedrun" responsibly, if you know what I mean. Meaning that I want to comprehend what I am doing with the limited tools I have (as I am meant to), before trying to get better, more powerful tools.

Comment: I don't know exactly what tools you have available to you, but the general way forward here it to project away from the null space then invert the new system. You will still have a null space component but imposing a minimal norm condition forces this to be zero.

Comment: Well, the tools I have at my disposition are what I outlined in my post + some theorems on inner products, how transposes behave, how orthogonal bases behave, etc. But the principal questions is just this: What does it mean, when the Gram matrix given by $A^TA$ is singular. What does it say about the matrix $A$ and how to circumvent it given the setup shown above. Also of note is that I have precisely found an example, where A itself has lineraly independent rows, but the Gram matrix still comes out as singular.

Comment: The Gram matrix being singular means that $A$ has linearly dependent columns: $A^TAx = 0 \implies x^TA^TAx = 0 \implies \|Ax\|=0 \implies Ax=0$. This means that $A$ does not have full rank and has nontrivial null space.

Comment: This requires one to form a basis of the column space of $A$ and consider the problem over that subspace, but that is typically done via the SVD or some modification of a QR decomposition.

Comment: Ahh, my bad, I somehow overlooked the fact that column and row space dimensions are not the same. Thank you.

Comment: They always have the same dimension.

Comment: My bad, what I mean to convey is that even though the rows of the matrix may be linearly independent, that doesn't translate to the column being linearly independent in any way. Wow, solid brain fart, sorry! :D